# Restore Central Administration Site

Tags: central-administration

looks like I accidentally deleted my Central Administration site running on port 43709. From the looks of it I still have the content database that has the info but I can't seem to be able to restore the site.

I've tried

```
stsadm -o createsite -url site_url:43709
```

then

```
stsadm -o addcontentdb -url site_url:43709 -databasename dbname -databaseserver dbserver
```

but it errors out with ****edited to provide complete error****

> Unable to continue with repair because you do not have access to the site at http://server:80/. Please fix this issue to continue.

Is there another way I can restore the central adminitration site?

Comment: oh and can't seem to run Configuration Wizard to restore it.

Comment: When you attach a content db which is already referred it gives you this GUID problem. That's when you get all these "database name already exists" or "content db assigned to another site" error. Can you post the entire configuration wizard error that you are getting. We need to solve that primarily.

Comment: updated the complete error message above

Answer (score 4):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093.aspx

You can reprovision Central Admin vis psConfig.exe.

Look into the the details of the adminvs command

i.e.

```
psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 8080 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm
```

As a suggestion, pick an easy to remember port for Central Admin (i.e. 10000) and use this every time you provision a SharePoint server. Easier than something like 43709.

Comment: will this continue to use the existing adminContentDB? I fear that creating a new central admin site would eliminate all the existing configurations.

Comment: Hi Neil, I ran this psconfig.exe, now my CA site shows me '400 Bad Request'.. Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Site content usually is not deleted and still exists on your hard drive. You should be able to create a new IIS site bound to the same port number and with its physical location set as the path to your central admin site content.

To find your CA site content, browse around your hard drive. Something like this:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\43709

All this info is stored in the config.db for your SharePoint farm. If you delete a
website in IIS and If it is CA that is missing, simply re-run the SharePoint Config Wizard and recreate CA.

Comment: yes I did find the site content. I've run the Config Wizard but it errors with "don't have permissions to http://web-url:80" not sure how to address that.

Comment: What is weird about this is I do create a new site and try to addContentDB to the new site but it always errors with "contentdb is assigned to another site"

Comment: which account you're using to log in and to restore? If understood it correctly you are using 43709 port, so why are you changing ports now?

Comment: not changing ports. When running the config wizard (GUI) that is the error it comes up with. There is no option to input anything.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably permission issue that is causing you this problem. Verify the following before running the configuration wizard again.

1. Check whether the SharePoint applications are running on an app pool account which has enough rights in the database server.
2. Try reentering the app pool accounts in IIS, by going to advanced settings on each app pool and then start and stop the app pools for a restart. Do an IIS Reset after everything.
3. Go to services.msc and check whether SharePoint services are running with proper accounts. If yes, try restarting those services, just in case.
4. Check your SharePoint db, by logging in with the app pool account to see whether it has access to the SharePoint config db.
5. I have also read that Firewall and antivirus settings in your machine can also block the ports for SQL Server and this could also cause similar issues. It would be good checking those too.
6. Try running your configuration wizard with "Run as administrator" mode now.
7. After all this, if it still does not bring your configuration wizard, try uninstalling and reinstalling SharePoint and then restore your central admin with the db that you have backed up.

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score -2):

`New-SPCentralAdministration -Port 43709` should create a new Central Admin Web site.