# Recreate web.config for Central Administration

Tags: 2010, web-config

I was experimenting with SharePoint 2010 in a VM.  After trying my hand with custom app development, I decided I wanted to free up the space used by Visual Studio and so I uninstalled it.  After I rebooted I found the `web.config` file for both my main SharePoint site and Central Administration are blank.  The files are ~90KB but are full of spaces. I was able to recover the `web.config` for the main SharePoint site by using one of the `web.config` backups stored next to the blank `web.config`. For Central Administration, no such backup exists.

Is there a way to create a new `web.config` file for Central Administration?

I do not believe I made any changes to the Central Administration site, but only used Central Administration to create site collections of the SharePoint application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recreate your central admin web application using `psconfig.exe`

```
psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 8080 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093.aspx

[Restore Central Administration Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27455/restore-central-administration-site)